# Image description box on image with css & html

Tags: css, html, image

I'm trying to create a image description box on the image and I want the image to a fade when you hover over the image.

**This is what I want to acheive:**
[image]

**On hover I want this:**
[image]

**This is what I got so far:**

HTML:

```
<div class="app-img-wrapper">
<a href="images/Example/pexels-photo-344544.jpeg" title="Image 1"> <img src="images/Example/pexels-photo-344544.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="App"> <h2><span>Image Text</span></h2> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.app-img-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
}

.app-img-wrapper h2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.app-img-wrapper h2 span{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see, I'm almost there but having trouble with matching the box to the image size. If anyone has any tips please suggest below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the span in your `h2`. Added some helper classes to everything, and am making the overlay out of a pseudo element of the `a` tag. Added some transitions so everything fades, but you can adjust that as you see fit.

```css
.app-img-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
}

.app-img-link:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.app-img-link:hover .app-img-text {
  background: rgba(34, 139, 34, 0.7);
  color: black;
}

.app-img {
  display: block;
}

.app-img-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background .5s, color .5s;
}

.app-img-link:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: 'Click to view info';
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-img-wrapper">
  <a href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="app-img-link" title="Image 1"> <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="img-responsive app-img" alt="App">
    <h2 class="app-img-text">Image Text</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```